# How to incrementally number report details and set 0 if no records, Access Reports

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-reports

I have an Access report with details (see image below). I have incremental numbering for the report details. I achieved this by creating a TextBox and setting it's Control Source: '=1' and Running Sum: 'Over Group'. This works well, but if I have no records the number shows up as 1 (I want this number to show up as 0). If I try to check if detail is NULL in VBA, it returns false if I have at least one Detail record in the entire report.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If there's no data doesn't that get reported in the NoData event and the report closes? Or are you forcing report to open with no records?

Comment: My report is based on a query that gets info from multiple tables. At the top, I have the Main Information (information about a Company), each Company has some Projects associated with it (this is the secondary information in yellow) .A Project may have some details associated with it (or no details), this is in red. Even if the Project has no Details it should show up for that Company. So I think the answer to your second question is yes (I have a left join that gets Project information (yellow) even if there are no Details (red) for that project, to show that the Project has been initiated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Try 3)

OK, so the red section *does* show up on a left join, because the query is returning `Null` for the missing records.

So, your *real* fix is to:

1. Select a detail field that that is always non-Null (I'll assume it is called `ID`)
2. Set the control source of your counter control to:

   ```
   =IIf(IsNull([ID]),0,1)
   ```

That way the running sum will show zero for emply detail groups.